# golang yaml support for jsonlines

Tags: json, go, yaml, jsonlines

I've been trying to get the go yaml package to parse a file with jsonlines entries.

Below is a simple example with three options of data to be parsed.

- Option one is a multi-doc yaml example. Both docs parse ok.
- Option two is a two jsonline example. The first line parses ok, but the second is missed.
- Option three is a two jsonline example, but I've put yaml doc separators in between, to force the issue. Both of these parse ok.

From reading the yaml and json specs, I believe the second option, multiple jsonlines, ought to be handled by a yaml parser.

My questions are:

- Should a YAML parser cope with jsonlines?
- Am I using the go yaml package correctly?

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "strings"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

var testData = []string{
    `
---
option_one_first_yaml_doc: ok_here
---
option_one_second_yaml_doc: ok_here
`,
    `
{option_two_first_jsonl: ok_here}
{option_two_second_jsonl: missing}
`,
    `
---
{option_three_first_jsonl: ok_here}
---
{option_three_second_jsonl: ok_here}
`}

func printVal(v interface{}, depth int) {
    typ := reflect.TypeOf(v)
    if typ == nil {
        fmt.Printf(" %v\n", "<null>")
    } else if typ.Kind() == reflect.Int || typ.Kind() == reflect.String {
        fmt.Printf("%s%v\n", strings.Repeat(" ", depth), v)
    } else if typ.Kind() == reflect.Slice {
        fmt.Printf("\n")
        printSlice(v.([]interface{}), depth+1)
    } else if typ.Kind() == reflect.Map {
        fmt.Printf("\n")
        printMap(v.(map[interface{}]interface{}), depth+1)
    }
}

func printMap(m map[interface{}]interface{}, depth int) {
    for k, v := range m {
        fmt.Printf("%sKey: %s Value(s):", strings.Repeat(" ", depth), k.(string))
        printVal(v, depth+1)
    }
}

func printSlice(slc []interface{}, depth int) {
    for _, v := range slc {
        printVal(v, depth+1)
    }
}

func main() {

    m := make(map[interface{}]interface{})

    for _, data := range testData {

        yamlData := bytes.NewReader([]byte(data))
        decoder := yaml.NewDecoder(yamlData)

        for decoder.Decode(&m) == nil {
            printMap(m, 0)
            m = make(map[interface{}]interface{})

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which part of the YAML specification makes you think JSONL is supported?

Comment: @Volker "8.2.3 Block Nodes", inside "9.1.3 Bare Documents", but I wasn't sure, hence the question. :)

Comment: 8.2.3 Will just get you a block node but no JSON parsing. I'm confused and out.

Answer (score 0):

jsonlines is newline delimited JSON. That means the individual lines are JSON, but not multiple lines and certainly not a whole file of multiple lines.

You will need to read the jsonlines input a line at a time, and those lines you should be able to process with go yaml, since YAML is a superset of JSON.

Since you also seem to have YAML end of indicator  (`---`) lines in your test, you
need to process those as well.

Comment: Using the yaml  Decode, this should handle the stream and hence the (---) or (...) terminators, right? And it seems to work for the first and second examples. So I don't need to handle these like I would if I used Unmarshall, correct, or am I missing something?

Comment: Most YAML parsers expect ***valid YAML*** in documents (i.e. between the end-of-indicator) lines. If there is more than one jsonlines, it is no longer a valid YAML file. How are you creating those multi-document YAML like files.

Comment: As @Volker pointed out, I was getting confused with the spec regarding 8.2.3, so I agree with the first two paragraphs of your answer and it answers my question, but your third paragraph refers to the parsing of the (---) which is handled correctly by yaml.Decode. Right?

Comment: That is only right if between the `---` you have valid YAML. I ask you once more: how are you creating those YAML files? Because if you do that yourself, there is much, much, easier solution.

Comment: The YAML are hand edited configs, currently at 48, describing the contents of plates of samples used in human genotyping. They are in a single file and they parse correctly, without any extra handling using the code I posted. The jsonlines were generated using python (jsonlines package) , and there are currently 4608 spread across 113 files, and growing.